# What should I do about trailing whitespace in JSHint 2.5.0?

Tags: javascript, jshint

According to [this](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.0) documentation trailing whitespace seems to have been removed.  How can I enforce whitespace checking while not using a feature that's been deprecated like `"white": true`?

Comment: But where you are using "white spaces"?
Consider whether they are needed.

Comment: Maybe my term is incorrect, I'm talking about spaces or tabs after a line that may accidentally get in there without immediately noticing in a text editor.

Comment: Use jsLint, it'll nag you about the messy white-spaces for sure : ). If you want to remove trailing white-spaces from your file, many text editors have a function for the task, for example Notepad++.

Comment: This is the goal of "jshint" show you problems and accidents so you can remove them (or fix them).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I am trying to enforce whitespace checking and v 2.5.0 will no longer do so in my current Grunt setup utilizing JSHint 2.5.0, whether I have a `"white"` attribute or not.

Comment: Forgive my confusion, I understand your question now. I thought you wanted to force "false", your doubt this will be ignored by default or will be validated by default. Really this I still can not be sure.

Comment: From what I understand they were removed by default, apparently if you use "true", then you are enabling again. At least that's what I did: "JSHint won't error if you have these options in your config or your files; it will simply ignore them."

Comment: @ShawnStrickland I update my answer, read "Alternative solution"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As other answers have stated, this functionality has been removed in JSHint 2.5.0, along with various other legacy features that were basically just leftovers from the original JSLint fork.

Whitespace linting is still a valuable tool though. It can be really annoying when diffs are polluted with endless whitespace changes because of some erroneous text editor setting that the committer forgot to switch off. The tool best suited to this job now in my opinion is [JSCS](https://github.com/mdevils/node-jscs) which provides validation of a wide range of style choices.

This separation leaves JSHint to analyse the code itself for potential problems, and JSCS to analyse the way the code is presented. I use both alongside each other in most projects now. The JSCS rule used to prevent trailing white space is [`disallowTrailingWhitespace`](https://github.com/mdevils/node-jscs#disallowtrailingwhitespace).

Answer (score 2):

As this excerpt:

> JSHint will not error if you have these options in your config or your files, it will simply ignore Them.

So you It can still use, but if you set the option to `true`.

> ### jshint 2.5.0
>
> The following options were removed: nomen, onevar, passfail, white,
>   gcl, smarttabs, trailing. In addition to that, indent no longer
>   provides warnings about indentation levels. You can still use it to
>   set your tab-width but it will be used only for character locations in
>   other warnings. JSHint won't error if you have these options in your
>   config or your files; it will simply ignore them.

Jshint 2.5.0: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.0

Jshint 2.5.1: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.1

### Alternative solution:

An alternative solution is to use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/), whenever you finish editing a code you can use the following:

`Edit > Blank Operations > Trim Trailing Space`

The result is something like this:

`[SPACE]if (something) {[SPACE]` to `[SPACE]if (something) {`

> Note: `[SPACE]` is only one example (replace by whitespace)

You can also configure notepad++ to replace tabs with spaces when you type, configure like this:

`Settings > Preferences > Tab Settings` and select "normal" (or other), tabs will be replaced with 4 spaces when you press tab in an edition.

This way you need not worry about this update "jshint" and can use it without fear of blanks.

### What to use in production code:

I recommend keeping two versions of your code, the "development version" and the "production version".

The development version should be the whole original code commented and unsing only by the team collaborating with the project, a good tool to keep the project (in case of open-source) would be the https://github.com

The production version should be compacted your original code (without comments and unnecessary spaces), a tool for this would be:
http://jscompress.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use multistr which will catch whitespace where it really hurts.

multistr
This option suppresses warnings about multi-line strings. Multi-line strings can be dangerous in JavaScript because all hell breaks loose if you accidentally put a whitespace in between the escape character () and a new line.